# Cassandra Cluster configuration

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing

I am trying to configure two windows  servers in my network as Cassandra cluster.

I did some reading in various sites and changed the below in Cassandra.yalm

after changing the default value of 127.0.0.1 to actual IP the Cassandra service is not starting.

I also added the map to actual IP to localhost in (windows) hosts file.

After doing the above change, the service is coming up when I start the service. it is stopping immediately.

The reason I am changing this IP is to make this a cluster with two node setup,

Please let me know if I miss some thing.
Version: Datastax community version of Cassandra 
Server : windows.

Thx
Muthu

Message from Cassandra.txt in logs dir:

ERROR [main] 2014-09-18 11:43:12,155 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 116) Fatal configuration error

org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml Caused by: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=seed_provider for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@34e5190a; No suitable constructor with 2 arguments found for class org.apache.cassandra.config.SeedProviderDef in 'reader', line 8, column 1: cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'

Comment: Any errors on your log?

Comment: Message from Cassandra.txt in logs dir :  ERROR [main] 2014-09-18 11:43:12,155 DatabaseDescriptor.java (line 116) Fatal configuration error
 org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml Caused by: Can't construct a java object for tag:yaml.org,2002:org.apache.cassandra.config.Config; exception=Cannot create property=seed_provider for JavaBean=org.apache.cassandra.config.Config@34e5190a; No suitable constructor with 2 arguments found for class org.apache.cassandra.config.SeedProviderDef
 in 'reader', line 8, column 1:
    cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'

Comment: By default the value in seeds is 127.0.0.1. As a first step to make it a cluster I changed it to actual ip instead of 127.0.0.1.  cassandra could not able to start due to this change. Let me know if I miss some  thing here.. Thx Muthu

Comment: Please share the "seed_provider" portion of your cassandra.yaml.

Comment: One of the keys to asking SO questions (or a question anywhere) is to include all relevant portions - what you were trying to do, the code (or in this case, the configuration change), and the error messages. Often people will just close questions rather than try to dig for the info. You have to make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: Hi Dan  Thanks for your response.

i am a new bee to cassandra. I just started customizing the cassandra.yaml. I did the changes as suggested by http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/initialize/initializeSingleDS.html  and made the Cassandra service up. 
since the ops agent was down I did changed the ip in opscenterd.conf as below

interface = 192.168.0.103. OpsCenter is still not working but my Cassandra is up.

let me know if miss any config for ops center. My next step is to do the similar config in another node and test the same.

Thx
Muthu

Comment: All the info you're providing via comments needs to be in the question instead. Make edits there and provide the relevant config file sections formatted for easy reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create Cassandra cluster you must have at least two nodes and configure /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml

**cassandra.yaml**

```
cluster_name: 'Some Cluster Name'
    listen_address: [Current IP]
    rpc_address: [Current IP]
    seed_provuder: 
        - seeds: "[Current IP], [Remote IP]"
```

> **Note**: seeds must have at least two IPs which must be reachable for each other

**Clean and start Cassandra instance**

```
sudo rm -rf  /var/lib/cassandra/*  /var/log/cassandra/*
```

> **Note**: Cassandra instance must be killed before cleaning those folders.